# Argument over rules not being followed

Tags: argumentation, virtue-ethics, rule-ethics

I strongly think that rules are meant to be followed. But, according to my colleagues, it doesn't matter if the parties involved in the violation of the rules do not engage in anything harmful to them or to others. Is this point that they make valid?

For example, in our hostel, girls are not allowed to be inside the men's hostel after 10 pm. Suppose I spot a girl in one of the rooms (within the men's hostel) after midnight. They are not engaging in anything immoral or suspicious. I argued with some of the students that rules are meant to be followed and not broken to maintain order. They just laughed at me and criticized me saying that it is my mindset that needs to be changed. All I said was that rules are meant to maintain law and order. Is what I am saying ethically correct and morally valid for a situation like this? How should I convey properly what I mean?

It would be helpful if the specific case that I mentioned is given importance while answering.

Comment: Is there an enforcement mechanism? If not, then it's not really a rule, it's just bad poetry. If there is, then have you engaged that mechanism?

Comment: @BobaFit It is a rule meant to be followed in our hostel.

Comment: Winning friends and influencing people again I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rule-following is a complex philosophical issue. Rules have many purposes, including:

- Preventing incidental harm by people not fully aware of potential consequences
- Acting as an external conscience for people who are immature or lack moral development
- Regulating behavior between individuals with differing view, values, and opinions
- Creating a conducive environment for some given purpose
- Instituting community standards for the protection and benefit of everyone
- etc.

Now, obviously mature men and women can spend time together without doing anything inappropriate, assuming they've developed a proper moral compass. However:

1. Not everyone (in any age group) has an effective moral compass
2. Not everyone is aware of the risks posed to themselves by others without properly developed consciences
3. Speculation and misperception (not to mention actual malfeasance) can irreparably damage the reputations of individuals and institutions

To be specific, there may be no direct harm to (say) Bob and Jill if they stay up in the men's hostel to the early morning hours chatting about whatever, asserting that Bob and Jill are both conscientious moral agents. But Frank may not be a conscientious moral agent, and might see Bob and Jill's late-night chat as as a signal that he can lure women to his own hostel room for less palatable purposes. Or Jane might misunderstand Bob and Jill's late-night meeting and start spreading rumors, which will damage the reputation of Bob, Jill, and the hostel itself. That might result in Bob and Jill being expelled from the hostel, so the hostel doesn't get the reputation of being 'that' kind of place.

There are cases where there is no harm in violating rules with discretion, and there are other cases where rules are badly made and should be directly confronted and intentionally broken. But those acts should be done conscientiously, and with awareness that breaking rules can create unintended consequences.

Comment: Exactly what is the harm if Bob and Jill have wild, passionate sex? You seem to have a problem with that.

Comment: @user4894: honestly, I like wild, passionate sex, and I have no problem with B&J engaging in it. I'm actually not worried about them at all, since I asserted up front that they are competent moral agents. My issue is with the secondary (unintended) consequences. It's nice to believe that what we do in private is our own solitary private business, but in the REAL world even private actions have certain public consequences that we ought to be mindful of. Unfortunately or not, we don't get to do what we want in the world without the world taking notice. Arguing otherwise is facile philosophy.

Comment: By that logic, anyone who has sex in a place they're not supposed to is setting a bad example for the entire world. You can't mean that as a general moral principle, can you? Two people have sex on a state beach and the entire world will take that as license to litter on their own local beach?

Comment: @user4894: I don't *personally* see the connection between sex and littering, but hey... no judgement. :-) But seriously, rules are rules for a reason.  Sometimes the reason is good, sometimes the reason is bad, but breaking it thoughtlessly is unwise. It's a moral decision adults get to make, with the social obligation that the decision is made judiciously.

Comment: We could use more of Thich Nhat Hanh's rule #14: "*Do not utter words that could cause the community to break.*"

Answer (score 1):

That heavily depends on the rules in question. Like some rules are meant to be broken. Like idk some warnings are meant to scare away inexperienced people and so being able to overcome what was warned against is the point. Some rules are more of a guideline meant to be adjusted or replaced later on and some rules are "meant to maintain the law and order".

But the crucial point is that these are only the intentions of the person making the rules and that doesn't mean that they are just, that you agree with the rules or that you even agree with the "law and order" that they are meant to enforce.

Like in the extreme, what if the rules tell you to kill an innocent person? Or command others to kill you? Would you disobey the rules endangering the status quo of law and order? Probably yes, because the status quo of law and order isn't all that great for you to begin with so it's not much that you'd sacrifice in that regard.

So the question is somewhat "What do these rules accomplish", "Do you agree with these goal", "What are the consequences of action or inaction" and so on.

Like should people be allowed to tell you how you should live your life? No, that's your decision. Would you disagree if someone tells you not to enter the hazardous area where lots of pollution will instantly kill you? Yeah despite a restriction to your life you probably agree that this is a good idea. If someone points a gun at you and commands you to do or not do something would you do it? Well probably depends on whether that thing is worth dying for.

So in terms of girls not being allowed in the men's hostel it's likely about the antiquated moral concepts of the person in charge of the hostel, than about some pressing issue, the rules are one sided and if you don't agree with them it's the landlord rather than the police and the general public who would come after you. Usually the landlord might has some house rules for their property but if it's about obscure and immoral request "the law" (that is of the state, country, jurisdiction) might allow you to ignore them or might even demand that you ignore them or might prevent him from punishing you for the violation of these laws. But that's a legal more than a philosophical question.

Anyway the most convincing argument for following rules is if these rules make sense and are agreeable. If they aren't it's mostly about authority often in that regard challenging that might be better than blindly accepting it, though again that heavily depends on the rules and the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Rules keep order.  That's why there are laws to physics, otherwise there would only be entropy with no life at all.  (Corollary:  One can conclude, therefore, that life co-evolved with physics -- because something)

The relevant issue is whether rules exhibit an abuse of power.  Should they be followed in that case?  It depends.  This issue of power is one that is thousands of years old.  There is some wisdom about it after such time.

In short, if you are dependent on the individual making the rules, you should probably follow them.  The follow-up question, however, is:  what makes you dependent?

Comment: Rules of physics are meant to be broken, it's just damn hard to do so ;)

Comment: @haxor789:  No.  You're not meant to break the laws of thermodynamics.  It shall remain impossible.  Thank you for your understanding on this matter.

Comment: You're completely ignoring the distinction between natural law and man-made law. Two entirely different things, not even related.

Comment: @Marxos I always obey the second law of thermodynamics. That's why my house is a mess!

Comment: @user4894:  No.  Even man-made rules follow a need to keep entropy from happening within our soul.  For example, what causes people to blow their brains out?  Science never answered that.  Have you?  Yet, the lack of understanding on this question has kept society from fixing itself -- or even worse, from not caring about people.  This creates entropy in our soul as a society and meaninglessness among each other.  Next time, take philosophy, not physics.

Comment: @Marxos What???

Comment: @user4894:  You know the internet is not exactly a place where it's hard to hear.  What about my comment didn't you understand before you just ask me to answer a useless question.

Comment: @Marxos I did not understand a single word of what you wrote, not even "a" or "the" in the context in which you used them. Suicide is the cause of society's ills and this is a response to the silly joke I made? I don't get it. I should study philosophy? I was thinking I should try to get better at making silly jokes.

Comment: @user4894:  Let me add a comma:  "You know, the internet is not exactly a place where it's hard to hear."  Do you understand that?  The use of the word "hear" is symbolic -- you can't hear on the internet, yet you asked me "What???" as if you didn't "hear" me.  But you did.  See.

Comment: @Marxos Having reviewed this dialog from back in December that you inexplicably chose to revivify today, I must once again ask: What????

Comment: @user4894:  No.  The timeline is schizoid.  Your message/reply appeared today.

Comment: Nobody can reasonably claim to know *why* there are laws of physics. We can observe there are regularities and make judgment about how it's a good thing, at most. Equating laws of physics and social rules is a fallacy of the highest order.

Comment: @user4894 "*You should let the wookie win.*"

Comment: @armand:  One *can* reasonably claim to know why -- if they have direct evidence of GOD, for example, then it is *perfectly* reasonable.

Comment: @Marxos so exactly as i said, nobody can reasonably claim to know why there are laws of physics, since no reasonable person can claim to have direct evidence of god.

Answer (score 1):

Rules are laws without the consequences or enforcement mechanisms of a law. Rules are more synonomous with guidelines. Without some sort of incentive (punishment or reward), rules will be circumvented as long as the reward/risk ratio is high enough for an individual. Sex presents an extremely high reward/risk ratio for the the young adults occupying a youth hostel provided there is no real enforcement mechanism.